# Error while running .navigateTo() protocol action: timeout

Tags: nightwatch.js

I updated the Nightwatch version to 1.0.19.
While Executing the script I have the following timeout issue in navigate() function.

here is the console output:

{ sessionId: '2aeb3cd9367d3580ae4ae705abca2a80',
     status: 21,
     value:
      { message: 'timeout',
        error:
         [ '  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)',
           '  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.4.0-1038-aws x86_64)' ] } }

`Error while running .navigateTo() protocol action: timeout`

..........................

Comment: Can you post the test that you wrote?

Comment: @Alapan      Registration (browser) { 
            const registerScreen = browser.page.registerPageObject();
            registerScreen.navigate()
                .pause(7000);
}